# How to show bookmark bar only on new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, tabs

Previously, in chrome, the booksmark bar was invisible when viewing actual web content, but present on the new tab page.  This is extremely practical as realistically, the only time I actually would open a bookmarked page is on a new tab.  I rebooted my computer today to find it to be missing from my new tab page.  I can turn the bookmarks bar on and off using settings or Ctrl + Shift + B, however, it now does so for navigated webp ages and my new tab.  Is there any way to return to this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This continues to be the behavior of Chrome in regards to the bookmark toolbar: When a new tab is opened in Chrome, the bookmark toolbar appears, even if you have turned off its display on active tabs with `Ctrl + Shift + B`. The only time that this is not the case is when an extension is being used that overrides the default "new tab" functionality.